# Conditional operation based on another cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I have in **column A** the months of the year, and in **column B** some numbers. What I need is to make operations with all numbers corresponding January, all numbers corresponding February, and so on. For example, the sum of all the numbers from January:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `4` is in B2, you have quite a few options, the simplest might be to create a table of months (say January in C2 down to December in C13) and in D2 copied down to suit:

```
=sumif(A:A,C2,B:B)
```

The most versatile might be to create a pivot table, say `m` in A1, `v` in B1 and select A:B, Data, Pivot table report..., Rows - Add field `m`, Values - Add Field `v`. Because you months seem to be strings they will not automatically be ordered chronologically but the fields may be summarised in a dozen ways other than SUM also.